# Quantum computing roadmap

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing

I have to create a roadmap for the quantum computing technology. Looking around I found the [timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_quantum_computing) on wikipedia that is pretty wide but does not highlight the key events in quantum computing research neither sets the possible future for research.

Could somebody help me to define which are key events in the quantum computing fields? When (and why) we started to explore this technology, for which milestones we passed through and (maybe) what we can set as future milestones?

Comment: [imho this question could be promoted to cstheory.se]

Comment: @vzn yes probably, is there a way to migrate it?

Comment: We do not normally migrate questions that are on-topic where they are, regardless of whether they are also on-topic elsewhere. We make the occasional exception for a question about theoretical computer science that goes unanswered here if it looks like it may be better suited for the research level of [cstheory.se]. But since you have had a satisfactory answer here, there is no point in migrating the question to CSTheory.SE any more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [Quantum Information Science and Technology Roadmapping Project](http://qist.lanl.gov/qcomp_map.shtml) is a very detailed roadmap prepared under ARDA ([Advanced Research and Development Activity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Research_and_Development_Activity)) around ~2004 with further refinements. Here is the [introduction/overview](http://qist.lanl.gov/pdfs/rm_intro.pdf). It had a panel of about 19 elite academic scientists/experts.

For a completely contrasting recent overview/review on progress to date/future prospects see this [controversial] paper [State of the Art and Prospects for Quantum Computing, M. I. Dyakonov](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1212/1212.3562.pdf) (2012).

Comment: should point out here that Dyakonov specifically broadly/critically analyzes/surveys the one decade progress of QM computing versus the in-retrospect-"optimistic" (to say the least) ARDA roadmap, showing some of the risks of attempting to build longrange roadmaps esp in this very tricky yet now high-effort, high-funded, high-profile area (where a good one would be extremely valuable and is very much needed). have not seen anyone else do so in a paper.

Comment: +1 for the link to Dyakonov's paper.  It's the best read I've had in a long time.  Incredibly funny (and wise (and wise-ass)) in addition to being informative.

Comment: thx, glad you enjoyed it! full disclosure here is a [response](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1211) by a semifamous QM computing researcher

Comment: @vzn i was aware about ARDA roadmap, is very good but definetly too long. More than a roadmap is a description of all details.